# Historic weather station data with hourly temporal resolution

Tags: meteorology, wind

I'm working with ERA5 weather data and am trying to understand some wind & temperature patterns that I'm seeing in my statistics. In order to do that I'd like to compare with some point observations (weather stations). My work requires hourly data of at least temperature, wind velocity and direction reaching back at least 1 year (ideally 10). I'm looking mainly for information from Europe but am open to data from other regions. The amount of data I need is fairly limited since I'd filter only certain days.

I've looked around but was unable to find a source with transparent access to such data. The closest I could find is WeatherUnderground (e.g.: https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/ITOULO102/table/2023-05-30/2023-05-30/daily), however there doesn't seem to be an API and there are some issues with the data (discretized wind direction for example).

So my question: Is there something better available? A register of weather stations (official or private) that provides data access as described above?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out the [ECAD](https://www.ecad.eu/dailydata/index.php) for European stations and the [DWD](https://www.dwd.de/EN/climate_environment/cdc/cdc_node_en.html;jsessionid=0DDD1E09A38F075C396C02C6020AA834.live11053) (German Weather Service). Both have some kind of ftp/open access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an API particularly, but I've dabbled around sites like [NCEI](https://ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-hourly/access), [Iowa Environmental Mesonet](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml) (from Iowa State), and [CoolWx](https://coolwx.com/userobs) (for PWS obs) and found some use from them on these topics.  Hopefully this is a start towards better info on this topic.